# Prestashop stubborn css cache

Tags: prestashop

I use prestashop 1.6.0.8
I want to modify css files. I disabled cahce and ccc from advanced parameters->performance. Set template compilation to force compilation. Deleted cache->smart->cache and compiled folders. But web page still creates css cache. 
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem solved. it was because of pagespeed module on cpanel.

Answer (score 0):

Did you empty the /cache/smarty/compile/ folder?

Everything in there except the index.php

This of course assuming you don't use third party solutions like Cloudflare which also caches the content.

Comment: yes I emptied  /cache/smarty/compile/ folder. I don't use third party solutions. but still calls css from cache. Is there a code that causes does not care cache configuration?

Comment: Nope, not really. On the same Advanced Preferences->Performance there is a setting on the bottom of the page for enabling the filesystem cache, should be set to Use cache = No. Is it in your case?

Answer (score 0):

This could also just be the browser cache? Did you try reloading the page after clearing browser cache?

Chrome Dev Tools (Firefox probably has something similar) has an option to disable the browser cache while dev tools is open.

Comment: yes I cleared browser cache. Also tried new installed browser and at a computer that never visited my website before.

Comment: when inspecting your site with dev tools, under the "sources" tab, in which folder is the css file? if it's in `themes/[your_theme]/cache/` then try clicking the "clear cache" button at the top right of the "advanced Parameters/ performance" page